# Python equivalent of Matlab's interp2

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation

I am trying to translate some Matlab code into Python, but I am stuck on Matlab's interpolate 2D function:

```
interp2(x, y, double(imcart), imx, imy);
```

Dimensions:
x: 388 x 388
y: 388 x 388
imcart: 388 x 388
imx: 194 x 180
imy: 194 x 180

The previous question I could find concerning this suggested using:

```
ip = interp2d(x, y, ps)
zi = ip(imx, imy)
```

But this `interp2d` never finishes, while the interp2 function in Matlab is instant.

Another suggestion is

```
RectBivariateSpline(x, y, ps, imx, imy)
```

But this fails with the error `TypeError: x must be strictly increasing`.

Anyone have any bright ideas?

Comment: The second error occurs because `RectBivariateSpline` works on a grid of point, therefore expects the values of `x` and `y` to be increasing (as hinted by the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)). Don't know why the first part is slow though

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then. The documentation for `interp2d` also suggestes using `RectBivariateSpline` as it is supposed to be a lot faster.

Comment: I tried using `scipy`'s functions for interpolation before and found them to be incredibly slow comparatively to Matlab. If you're doing some image processing, have you tried using `OpenCV`? I found some of its interpolation functions to be much faster than `scipy`. Are you doing any image warping/transformations or just trying to downsample an image?